# Make Firefox save new bookmarks in the Bookmarks Menu (not Other Bookmarks)

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

Recently, Firefox has changed the default folder for newly created bookmarks (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) from the Bookmarks Menu to "Other Bookmarks".

Is there some way to change that back? Or some alternate method instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>?

**EDIT**

A native way to do this (without an add-on) would be best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been a popular topic of [discussion on the Mozilla Support Forums](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1195435):

> Before Firefox quantum, when pressing Ctrl+D, the created bookmark was
>   put in the bookmarks menu by default (unlike clicking the star
>   bookmark button, which defaulted to unsorted bookmarks). After
>   updating to quantum, the default location is "Other bookmarks" - the
>   same as pressing the star button.
>
> How do I restore the old behaviour?

Their moderators chimed in to say that there currently isn't a built-in way to restore the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> functionality to its former state. However, they also suggested that you can restore the previous <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> capability with a relatively new add-on, [Default Bookmark Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/default-bookmark-folder/):

> *Firefox built-in bookmarking:*
>
> This feature only affect bookmarks added through the built-in Firefox
>   bookmark icon or shortcut (Ctrl+D), or through the context menu.
>
> You can:
>
> - Select where the new bookmarks will be added
> - Choose to add the new bookmarks to the top or the bottom of the    selected folder

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same thing, but you can force Firefox to prompt you for a location every time you add a new bookmark by going to any bookmark page, clicking *Bookmarks --> Edit this bookmark*, and choosing "Show Editor When Saving"

[image: Show Editor When Saving]